# UIPasteboard says it has a string but the string is nil

Tags: ios, swift, uipasteboard

UIPasteboard says it has a string but the string is nil:

```
(lldb) p UIPasteboard.general.hasStrings
(Bool) $R2 = true
(lldb) po UIPasteboard.general.string
nil
```

Comment: what is the value for ```UIPasteboard.general.strings```?

Comment: @klinger It contains a 0 element array. The docs say `.string` will contain the first element of the `.strings` array.